# What is the first question on the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion

What is the first question that was asked on the Worldbuilding website?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you order the questions by date, and go to the last page of the list, you find that the first question listed there is [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1/30492), asked on Sep. 16th 2014 at 18:19.

As VLAZ pointed out, this question is the first question as well as the oldest still visible question. Its ID is 1, and since the IDs are sequential, it's a guarantee that it's the first one.